# Why authorizedRoute not responding as expected despite seeing a successful redirect in the logs?

Tags: kotlin, redirect, routes, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I have the following code that should redirect to the "/authorized" endpoint when the response is true.

```
val response = userDataSource.saveUserInfo(user = user)
logger.debug("check response: $response")
if (response) {
    app.log.info("USER SUCCESSFULLY SAVED/RETRIEVED in response sub: $sub, name $name")
    call.sessions.set(UserSession(id = sub, name = name))
    call.respondRedirect("/authorized")
    val redirectLocation = call.response.headers[HttpHeaders.Location]
    logger.debug("Redirected to: $redirectLocation")
} else {
    app.log.info("ERROR SAVING THE USER")
    call.respondRedirect("/unauthorized")
}
```

In the logs, I can see that I enter this branch, and the log looks as follows:

```
22:29:14.735 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] INFO  Application - USER SUCCESSFULLY SAVED/RETRIEVED in response sub: 100689333849658126849, name Vadim Morozov
22:29:14.765 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] INFO  Application - 302 Found: POST - /token_verification -> /authorized
22:29:14.765 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] DEBUG io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun - Redirected to: /authorized
```

I also have a authorizedRoute routing, which should respond with a success message when receiving a request to "/authorized":

```
fun Routing.authorizedRoute() {
    application.log.info("authorizedRoute")
    authenticate("auth-session") {
        get("/authorized") {
            application.log.info("authorizedRoute authorized")
            call.respond(
                message = ApiResponse(success = true),
                status = HttpStatusCode.OK
            )
        }
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, this routing does not work as expected.

**UPD**:
Also here is the Authentication code

```
fun Application.configureAuth() {
    this.log.info("configureAuth")
    install(Authentication) {
        session<UserSession>(name = "auth-session") {
            validate { session ->
                this@configureAuth.log.info("User session: $session")
                session
            }
            challenge {
                this@configureAuth.log.info("User session: unauthorized")
                call.respondRedirect("/unauthorized")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Session:

```
fun Application.configureSession() {
    this.log.info("configureSession")
    install(Sessions) {
        val secretEncryptKey = hex("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
        val secretAuthKey = hex("02030405060708090a0b0c")
        cookie<UserSession>(
            name = "USER_SESSION",
            storage = directorySessionStorage(File(".sessions"))
        ) {
            transform(SessionTransportTransformerEncrypt(secretEncryptKey, secretAuthKey))
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is my Main class:

```
internal fun Application.module() {

    install(Koin) {
        modules(getKoinModule())
    }

    val localSource by inject<LocalSource>()

    install(Routing) {
        api(application = application, localSource = localSource)
    }

    configureMonitoring()
    configureAuth()
    configureSession()

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
            call.respond(cause.toString())
        }
    }

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem with the following code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/f74579c2c6f69b5cb0decadb074b3441.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman in general, the implementation is similar to yours, I updated the code, but I could not detect the error, namely why the redirect is not processed when calling `call.respondRedirect("/authorized")`
Although if I call a successful code instead of call.respondRedirect("/authorized") immediately, then everything returns ok
```call.response(
    message = ApiResponse(success = true),
    status = HttpStatusCode.OK
)```

Comment: Do you use a web browser or another HTTP client? Can you upload the updated gist, which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman yes, I use localhost
and solved the problem with checkHttpMethod = false, but in any case, when a redirect occurs, I have to process a POST request to /authorized(AuthorizedRoute.kt), although in theory it should be GET. But I have to make such a crutch.
Here is the updated code, I can also add you to the project on github, so that you can understand the situation more, if you want, of course. https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/69a3a1a61ae74b69e525c430c235b6c8

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the initial request for a token was made using the POST method, and when we received a response, we invoked call.respondRedirect("/authorized"), which, as a result, also accepted the POST method. It was decided to enable the processing of the authorized route with both GET and POST methods. I'm not sure how long this will remain the correct solution, but it currently works.

```
fun Routing.authorizedRoute() {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    route("/authorized") {
        get {
            logger.debug("authorizedRoute authorized GET")
            call.respond(
                message = ApiResponse(success = true),
                status = HttpStatusCode.OK
            )
        }

        post {
            logger.debug("authorizedRoute authorized POST")
            call.respond(
                message = ApiResponse(success = true),
                status = HttpStatusCode.OK
            )
        }
    }
}
```